# using Python to pass a variable to SQL select query in where clause when access MySQL database

Tags: mysql-python

I am using Python 3 to access a MySQL database. When I try to pass a variable to a select query I get no results. If I use the condition inside the select query I get a result.

The header code is:
`import mysql.connector`
`from mysql.connector import Error`

The query which returns a result is:
`sql_select_query = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE price > 7"`
`cursor.execute(sql_select_query)`
`record = cursor.fetchall()`

The query which doesn't return a result (but runs without error) is:
`fishvalue = "7.50"`
`sql_select_query = """SELECT * FROM menu WHERE price = %s"""`
`cursor.execute(sql_select_query,(fishvalue,))`
`record = cursor.fetchall()`

What is the correct systax

Comment: You should use `?` instead of `%s`.

Comment: If I use  "?" I get the following error "Failed to get record from MySQL table: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"

Comment: If I use  "?" I get the following error 'Failed to get record from MySQL table: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement'

Comment: I just realized that 'sql_select_query = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE price = %s" ' should have been written as '(sql_select_query = ("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE price = %s")'